# Reading into a 2D vector

Tags: c++, input, vector, 2d, tostring

I am having an issue reading from a file into a 2D vector. I am new to c++ and I am not seeing the issue with my code.

the file follows this pattern.

```
5
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
...
```

My algorithim to read it...

```
void Similarity::readData(Scanner& inStream){
        dataLength = inStream.nextInt();
        while(inStream.hasNext()){
                vector<int> temp;
                int tempInt = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < dataLength; ++i){
                        tempInt = inStream.nextInt();
                        temp.push_back(tempInt);
                        temp.clear();
                }
                theData.push_back(temp);
                theData.clear();
        }
}
```

And my algorithim to print it.

```
string Similarity::toString(){
        string result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < theData.size(); ++i){
                for(int j = 0; j < dataLength; ++j){
                        result += convertInt(theData[i][j]);
                }
                result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
}

string Similarity::convertInt(int number){
        stringstream s;
        s << number;
        return s.str();
}
```

There is no output from the toString, is it the readData or the toString I need to work on?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, what is the issue that you're having with it? What goes wrong when you run the program?

Comment: There is nothing being printed to the output file from the toString function. When I add print statements into the readData. The data seems to be getting there.

Comment: There's no reason to use clear in readData. It throws away the data you've just added, that's what the problem is. What was your reason for using clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This section of code is meaningless (aisde from consuming the number from the stream, at least):

```
                    tempInt = inStream.nextInt();
                    temp.push_back(tempInt);
                    temp.clear();
```

since `temp.clear()` immediately removes the object inserted with push_back().

Same applies to this

```
            theData.push_back(temp);
            theData.clear();
```

I think you do need a `temp.clear()` where you now have `theData.clear()` tho'.

Comment: Haha, wow. It works, thank you. I was told that the .clear() was sort of like a flush() and that it was necessary.